Did Steven Pinker test (or propose testing) if ADHD patients could sit still for 5 minutes while in front of "6 legos and an over turned lamp"?


Harvard professor Steven Pinker proposed a study once where people with ADHD were told they would get $100 if they were able to sit still on a chair in a room for only 5 minutes.  In front of them was a table with 6 legos and an over turned lamp.  Not one person got the money.
(Source: Reddit's r/adhdmeme, current score 18k.)

I'd like to fact-check this meme.  I didn't immediately find the answer by Googling steven pinker adhd lego lamp, although there is a Harvard professor Steven Pinker who is an experimental cognitive psychologist.
Question: Did Steven Pinker test (or propose testing) if ADHD patients could sit still for 5 minutes while in front of "6 legos and an over turned lamp"?

Edit: After posting this question, the above-mentioned Reddit post (44k score) has been deleted for the following reason:

Your post/comment has been removed because it either contains, or is advocating for, misinformation.
Nonsense on the face of it.
Don't believe everything you see online.


The text in the image states clearly that Pinker "proposed" a study, not that it was ever performed. Of course nobody got money from a study only talked about. Since nothing is claiming he did it, there is nothing notable about the claim you are questioning.

Okay, I edited.  The notability comes from the (now) 35k+ people who upvoted the meme, not from whether or not it's only proposed.  Currently, all the evidence I have is "some guy on Reddit said so", and it's quite common for Redditors to misstate scientists' claims and have poor language skills.  For all I know, it could be totally made up.

He's alive and has a public email address (pinker@wjh.harvard.edu) so you or anyone here could simply ask him.

@NateEldredge I dropped him a mail. Lets see if he has the time to answer us.

Quote = Dear Correspondent,
Email has been coming in far more quickly than I can reply to it. I am prioritizing the time-sensitive messages, and can’t promise to reply to the growing backlog of non-urgent correspondence in a timely fashion. I will save your letter though, and reply as time permits. Thanks for your patience and understanding.

Seems the reddit post vanished

@BernhardDöbler here is an archive link: https://archive.is/lCvKv

Hey, the photo of professor Pinker is included in the meme, so it must be legit, otherwise why would they have had included his photo if it was not him who did it? (/sarcasm)

It is also worth considering whether any research motivation would have existed for this study. This would add little to scientific knowledge on ADHD, and doesn't address any relevant issue for assessment or management. Consequently, it is hard to imagine that a subject matter expert would even propose it

Nothing like this ever took place. It is a complete fabrication.
I mailed pinker@wjh.harvard.edu with following letter:

Dear sir,
Have you ever proposed a study where people with ADHD would be told they would get $100 if they were able to sit still on a chair in a room for only 5 minutes?
I'm writing to you on behalf of skeptics on stack exchange. (Did Steven Pinker test (or propose testing) if ADHD patients could sit still for 5 minutes while in front of "6 legos and an over turned lamp"?) The site is about applying scientific skepticism. I can think of no better source to this claim than the primary source.
Full claim is a bit longer:
Quote:
Harvard professor Steven Pinker proposed a study once where people with ADHD were told they would get $100 if they were able to sit still on a chair in a room for only 5 minutes. In front of them was a table with 6 legos and an overturned lamp. Not one person got the money.
/quote
Can you comment whether this is complete imagination or does it bear resemblance to something that took place?
Yours,
[pinegulf]

He responded with following letter back:


Dear [Pinegulf],
Nothing like this ever took place. It is a complete fabrication.
Best,
Steve


Though I suspect this is true, a skeptic might wonder if this correspondence is also a complete fabrication, and the event could still have happened.

@Beska Fair enough. I can provide more screenshots of the mails should you require them.

Honestly, I don't think it should be necessary...my was more a reminder to just remain skeptical in general.  That said, if you did provide them, it could only help (and might help keep the poor professor from getting a deluge of emails from everyone under the sun trying to independently verify the same thing.)

I am now growing skeptic of whether this whole skeptics.stackexchange.com thing is a real web site, frequented by real people, having real conversations, or...

Skeptics.SE skepticism is a conspirac theory.

Could Pinker be lying since it's embarassing?

It's not hard to imagine that he "proposed" this in casual conversation or suggesting it in an interview, not a formal research project.

@Barmar that was exactly my first thought, too.

@CJR - Definitely possible, but unless and until someone can find something suggesting that he actually said this besides a random anonymous Reddit meme, I think this answer is the best one can do.

@MikeNakis ever seen the Truman Show? I'm not allowed to tell you, but maybe try poking the back of your elevator ;)

It's going to get really odd if somebody now displays an 'email from Professor Pinker' stating the reverse, telling us how the project went and what the results were . . . . . .

@NigelJ Even better, someone could deep fake an interview with him talking about the project.

@Barmar: mind you, even if we suppose that the claim "Pinker once idly proposed this experiment but it was never conducted and he has since forgotten or is denying it" is true...  the claim under discussion says, "Not one person got the money", which is clearly intended to imply (incorrectly, and perhaps dishonestly) that the experiment did take place. If the intent were to make the former claim, they'd leave that bit off, or they'd say "the experiment never took place".

Rather like if I said, "not one of Barmar's allegations about Steven Pinker is true, and all were declared false by US courts" -- that statement is vacuously true since you've made no allegations about Pinker. But the answer to the question "did Barmar lose a court case over his Steven Pinker allegations" is still "no, he did not, despite there being some weaselly way to interpret the claim which makes it sort-of-true"!

@SteveJessop Sometimes people spreading disinformation intentionally use language like that to create plausible deniability. "I never actually said that the experiment took place."
